# Display username in top div using cookies in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5.5

"Hi, I am using Laravel 5.5 I want to display username in top div, I am not using Auth, writing logic manually. Also can any one tell me how to use cookies to store username ? Thanks in advance."

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
// Creating a cookie, with a basic value.
$cookie = cookie('key', 'value');

// Retrieving a cookie.
$cookie = cookie('key');
```

You can read the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#cookies)

Comment: Thanks for the cookie answer but what can I do about username in top nav ? Thanks.